# How do I manage tasks so can track status / cancel

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task

I am trying to automate some excel files so can refresh and then email out.

I currently do this by a queue method, but I have an issue where I may have 2 files that need to be sent at 10:00, 1 of the files take 2 mins to refresh, the other takes 5 mins to refresh, I then have another file which should be sent at 10:05, this is having to wait until others have complete.

With some help I have got as far as being able to create a list of tasks and start them, I have disabled WaitAll as I need the software to continue running in case need to trigger some more tasks, Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)() will be outside the procedure so can be used.

I am restricted to VB 2010 & .Net 4.0 this is why I am using Task.Factory.StartNew and not using Task.Run

```
    Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((Sub() OpenExcel("C:\Temp\Excel\Book1.xlsx"))))
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((Sub() OpenExcel("C:\Temp\Excel\Book2.xlsx"))))
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((Sub() OpenExcel("C:\Temp\Excel\Book3.xlsx"))))

     ‘ Disable if don’t wish to wait, will continue to run.
    'Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray)
```

I have been reading around and have been getting more confused I have found something about cancellation tokens, but everything I find is in C and I am unable to convert, they suggest changing to below which is more equivalent to task.run

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((Sub() OpenExcel("C:\Temp\Excel\Book1.xlsx")), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default))
```

What I want to do is get stats of a task in the list so I know the status and when it completes etc also the ability to cancel a task if required

Help appreciated

Comment: I think you could start the first two Tasks then use `Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(Sub() 'Last Task)` to start the last task, maybe delaying until it's the right time. But I really don't remember how it was in 2010 :)

Comment: The idea is so I can add more task as and when and be able to cycle the listof tasks to determine its status to see if completed etc, then remove it from the task list